# WPF Load and Bind dynamically

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have come up with a wonderful design for a screen in our WPF MVVM application and now having a lot of issues implementing it.

So I have a screen which I want to display a large list of databound rows.
Data is returned asynchronously.
Each row contains an expander, so looks something like

```
+ expander 1
+ expander 2
+ expander 3
+ expander 4
```

Works nicely load new rows when the user scrolls down the list.

Now for the part, I can't do, when the user expands the item I would like to dynamically load the data to be displayed in the expanded section of the row.

```
+ expander 1

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock/>
        <TextBlock/>
        <DataGrid/>
    </StackPanel>

+ expander 2
+ expander 3
+ expander 4
```

So the expanded data is to display further text and sub-rows

So thoughts of a trigger for IsExpanded but not sure how to trigger and return data to be bound in the controls within the body of the expander

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about dynamic or asynchron?

Comment: Well its kind of both, thats where I am coming undone. The root level is async, the child of the expander is to be dynamically read and populate. Want to do this due to the large amount of data and the child also contains multiple rows in the datagrid

Answer (score 0):

So the way to do that is:

1. Create a class lets say ExpanderRowModel
2. Create a DataTemplate for that class that displays the expander, closed by default, with all data inside when you open it, bound to the corresponding ExpanderRowModel.
3. Create a Property in the ViewModel that returns a collection of ExpanderRowModel
4. Bind that collection in a ListView or other ItemsControl you like.

Comment: Thats how I would do it if the root level of the collection was asynchronous. I dont know how to take the async collection and to populate each item into a view model. Is that possible?

Comment: What issue do you see with my solution that the async loading might cause? What do you mean by "async collection"?

Comment: The root level (expander) is return async, the expanded content contains another data grid with multiple rows.So I cannot return all the data in one call.I want the expanded content to be loaded on command